# Find all files with specific extensions that contains a string

Tags: command-line, files, find

I'd like to know how could I find all files whose extension can be `.xml` and `.py` that contain the string "Jason" under a path "./" recursively?

Or how could I exclude `.po` from the search?

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with grep only (without using find):

```
grep --include=\*.{xml,py} -Rl ./ -e "Jason"
```

And to exclude .po:

```
grep --exclude=*.po --include=\*.{xml,py} -Rl ./ -e "Jason"
```

Comment: Simple, to the point.  Works well.  Might I suggest error output suppression for files it can't read through?  +1

Answer (score 4):

Try the following command.  It will search only in the `.xml` and `.py` files for your name:

```
find . -type f \( -iname \*.xml -o -iname \*.py \) | xargs grep "Jason"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beaten me by a second :) I'm using -exec though

Comment: @Serg LOL.  I do like your answer by the way!  +1

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with combining `find` and `grep`. Here is a small demo - I have test directory with 6  txt and rtf files, two of which contain string "Jason".

```
CURRENT DIR:[/home/xieerqi/testdir]
$ find . -type f \( -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.rtf" \) -exec grep -iR 'jason' {} +                                        
./foo1.txt:Jason
./bar1.txt:Jason

CURRENT DIR:[/home/xieerqi/testdir]
$ ls                                                                                                                       
bar1.rtf  bar1.txt  bar2.rtf  bar2.txt  foo1.rtf  foo1.txt  foo2.rtf  foo2.txt

CURRENT DIR:[/home/xieerqi/testdir]
$ find . -type f \( -iname "*.txt" -o -iname "*.rtf" \) -exec grep -iR 'jason' {} +                                        
./foo1.txt:Jason
./bar1.txt:Jason
```

We find all the files with txt and rtf extensions here and give them all as parameters to grep. The `.` means search in current directory, but you could specify another path and `find` will descend into that directory and subdirectories, to search recursively.

Replacing extensions with yours, the final answer is

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.xml" -o -iname "*.py" \) -exec grep -iR 'jason' {} +
```

Comment: I like it Serg.  =)  It runs quickly on my system as well.  Results were returned in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
grep -r "Jason" ./ | grep .xml; grep -r "Jason" ./ | grep .py
```

That will display the output of any files containing `Jason` and limit it to filenames containing `.xml` or `.py`.

If you want to just exclude `.po`, then try this:

```
grep -r "Jason" | grep -v .po
```

Comment: Hmm, i run the first line and it throws everything that contains py (all filers called py) and also didn't exclude .po

Comment: I would not do this because it searches in all files and that can take a long time. Why looking in files you know you do not want. Grep should be limited to search only in .xml and .py files.

Answer (score 0):

How I understand from your question above, u need to show all files with "Jason" string into. So, may be this can help you:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.py" \) | grep -r "Jason" | cut -d':' -f1 | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution probably has been given already by nobody, however when the tool doesn't support searching a directory recursively for filenames one can enable the `globstar` option of `bash` and perform a recursive globbing:

```
shopt -s globstar; grep -F -l Jason **/*.{xml,py}
```

```
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ tree -a
.
└── dir1
    └── dir
        ├── containing_Jason.py
        ├── containing_Jason.txt
        ├── containing_Jason.xml
        ├── not_containing_Jason.py
        ├── not_containing_Jason.txt
        └── not_containing_Jason.xml

2 directories, 6 files
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ shopt -s globstar
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ grep -F -l Jason **/*.{xml,py}
dir1/dir/containing_Jason.xml
dir1/dir/containing_Jason.py
```

The equivalent feature in `zsh` is enabled by default:

```
grep -F -l Jason **/*.{xml,py}
```

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % tree -a                       
.
└── dir1
    └── dir
        ├── containing_Jason.py
        ├── containing_Jason.txt
        ├── containing_Jason.xml
        ├── not_containing_Jason.py
        ├── not_containing_Jason.txt
        └── not_containing_Jason.xml

2 directories, 6 files
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % grep -F -l Jason **/*.{xml,py}
dir1/dir/containing_Jason.xml
dir1/dir/containing_Jason.py
```